# How do a restrict create file in directory while allowing delete file

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I have a regular linux filesystem and part of it is used with sftp.

My goal is for sftp-user to **list** and **get** files in a subdirectory.
The user must also be able to **delete** files in that subdirectory.
And finally, I do NOT want that user to be able to **upload** files into that subdirectory.

I struggle with the filepermissions for this subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot do this with file system permissions alone.

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793507/rm-cannot-remove-directory-permission-denied), creating or deleting a file is actually a modification of the directory that contains the file. For that, the user needs to have a "w" permission to this directory. But at the same time, your requirements contradict each other - the user can either both create and delete files, or none of the above.

Apparently you need some kind of an additional authorization mechanism (maybe some web service, or a remotely callable script) to delete or upload the files, and then apply the authorizations there.

**Edit:**
For instance, you could create a REST webservice running with a separate user account that has "w" permission to the directory. You need to perform very strict checking of the passed arguments and authenticate the users, otherwise a hacker could wreck your system.

Comment: Thanks @roccobaroccoSC. This was my suspicion that the **w** on a directory is both create and delete files. I was hoping for some smart workaround with stickybits or something. Well, well. I can't create any other services in this projekt so my next step will be to investigate if `ssh_config` has something for preventing creating files or maybee limiting them to zero size.